# Repeater content not visible after UpdatePanel PreRender

Tags: c#, updatepanel, repeater, updateprogress, prerender

I have a repeater which i am trying to load after the page has loaded and have stumbled across the PreRender event. I have everything set up but the content of the repeater is not showing - the weird thing is that when i inspect the html, the code is there, just not displaying in the browser.

```
    <asp:updatepanel id="panel1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional" onprerender="upUpdatePanel_PreRender">
<contenttemplate>
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="mainContentRptr" onitemdatabound="bindDepts">
<headertemplate>
<div id="products-tabs-content" class="row tab-content">
    </headertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
    <div class="tab-pane" id='<%# eval("dept_id") %>
        '> <asp:repeater runat="server" id="prodRepeater" onitemcommand="itemToCart">
        <headertemplate>
        .... </headertemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
        .... <asp:repeater runat="server" id="condRptr">
        <headertemplate>
        .... </headertemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
        .... </itemtemplate>
        <footertemplate></footertemplate>
        </asp:repeater>
        </itemtemplate>
        <footertemplate>
    </div>
    </footertemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
</div>
<!-- End .tab-pane -->
</itemtemplate>
<footertemplate>
</footertemplate>
</asp:repeater>
</contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

As you can see a few nested repeaters... i also have my UpdateProgress control

```
<asp:UpdateProgress id="updateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="panel1">
                                        <ProgressTemplate>
                                            <div style="position: relative; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: white; opacity: 0.7;margin:0 auto">
                                                <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/loader.GIF" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 10px; position: relative; top: 45%;margin: 0 auto" />
                                                <br/>
                                                <span style="font-size: 16pt;font-weight: bold">Bulding your menu</span>
                                                <br/>
                                                <span>Please wait</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </ProgressTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

and then the following to trigger the delayed load

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                                        function pageLoad(sender, e) {
                                            if (!e.get_isPartialLoad()) {
                                                __doPostBack('<%= panel1.ClientID %>', 'aaaa');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </script>
```

and server side...

```
protected void upUpdatePanel_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == panel1.ClientID &&
                Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "aaaa")
            {
                populateRepeaters(); //This has databind for each repeater
            }
        }
```

This works without the prerender but loading speeding will vary depending on data etc so i wanted to have it load after the page loaded.

Any help would be appreciated guys! :)

Comment: never mind - turns out it was something simple, i had a repeater sitting out of the updatepanel that controlled the visibility of everything above. it was populated in the prerender event but did not display. Ive moved it inside the panel and everyhting is now working :)

Answer (score 0):

a repeater was sitting out of the updatepanel that controlled the visibility of everything above. it was populated in the prerender event but did not display. Ive moved it inside the panel and everyhting is now working